# In a Linear Programming Problem, how is Degeneracy affected by the number of variables and constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

In an LPP, with m constraints and n variables.
How does the number of constraints and variables affect the degeneracy of the system?

Comment: there is no direct relation between number of constraints and variables and degeneracy